# AWS: Allow IAM to only one EC2 instance and one S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i tried multiple Policy JSONs from the web, but not a single one worked.

I have one IAM user i want to give full access but only to one EC2 instance and one S3 bucket. How to do that? On the web i can find many of those Policy JSONs to try, but none of them are working. I guess these are not valid with the latest AWS console anymore? Even the official AWS documentation gives me one example, but its not working for the IAM user.

One i found to provide access to one specific S3 bucket. Policy is assigned to the user.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ArnEquals": {
                "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::178880795068:user/testuser"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: "its not working" - is not specific. Exactly what is happening? Any errors? How to reproduce the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "access but only to one EC2 instance"? What type of access? SSH, RDP, Web, FTP? Please note that normal SSH connection to an Amazon EC2 instance are secured via Keypairs, which are unrelated to IAM. However, you could use IAM to control access to EC2 Instance Connect or AWS Systems Manager Access Manager. Or do you mean "access" as in giving them the ability to create, start and stop EC2 instances? Please Edit your Question to add all of these details.

Answer (score 0):

For EC2 instance, you can try tagging the EC2, and then in the policy add something like this

```
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "ec2:ResourceTag/UserName": "${aws:username}"
    }
  }
```

with all actions you need to provide to user